# What does this PHP syntax mean and why is this variable NaN?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

question marks are hard to search for in google.

What does this mean step by step?

```
 $page = isset($_POST['page'])?$_POST['page']:"0";
```

I am guessing it means if `Post['page']` is set use that value and if not use `0`? but i dont get it in detail. Also when I do `var_dump($page)` i get `"NaN"` ; even though `POST['page']` is not set to anything yet. What's going on?

--> For full disclosure, I am using this Javascript function to pass the value of page..for a "load more"/pagination functionality.

```
$(function(){
    $("#more").click(loadPosts);
    loadPosts();
      var count = 0;
        var num = 2;
    function loadPosts() {
        $(".loading").show("fast");
        count += num;
        $.post("load.php", {'page': count}, function(data){
            $("#contents").append(data);
            $(".loading").hide("fast");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?:` syntax is called the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and does exactly what you think. If the first part (before the `?`) is truthy, the first option (before the `:`) is used; if not, the second option is.

The error that you're getting is because you haven't set your number values yet. This is how the browser reads your code:

```
$(function(){
    function loadPosts() {
        $(".loading").show("fast");
        count += num;
        $.post("load.php", {'page': count}, function(data){
            $("#contents").append(data);
            $(".loading").hide("fast");
        });
    }
    var count;
    var num;
    $("#more").click(loadPosts);
    loadPosts();
    count = 0;
    num = 2;
});
```

As you can see, `count += num` will be set *before* `var count = 0` and `var num = 2` are run, since `loadPosts()` is run before they are set. This is because of something called "hoisting", where function and variable declarations are moved to the very top of their containing scope.

Because you're trying to add `undefined` to `undefined` (since neither variable has been set yet), you get `NaN`: "not a number".  To fix this, move the function and variable declarations to the top of the scope, before you call `loadPosts`:

```
$(function(){
    function loadPosts() {
        $(".loading").show("fast");
        count += num;
        $.post("load.php", {'page': count}, function(data){
            $("#contents").append(data);
            $(".loading").hide("fast");
        });
    }
    var count = 0;
    var num = 2;
    $("#more").click(loadPosts);
    loadPosts();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `?` operator is called the ternary operator, you can look that up for more about it. But you understood it correctly.

Basically the code means: If the variable was set, then use it, otherwise default it to 0. (In php strict mode you can not access an array index that does not exist, so this code avoids that error.)

NaN means not a number - but PHP doesn't use (Edit: rarely uses) that, it was probably sent from Javascript, most likely because you tried to divide a number by 0 (presumably in the context of calculating the page). I don't see anything in the code you posted that does that, but perhaps it happens somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

`VARIABLE = (CONDITION) ? VALUE1 : VALUE2;` is short for

```
if (CONDITION)
    VARIABLE = VALUE1;
else
    VARIABLE = VALUE2;
```

You can use a similar notation to abbreviate conventional `if-else` statements:

`(CONDITION) ? FUNCTION1 : FUNCTION2;` is short for

```
if (CONDITION)
    FUNCTION1;
else
    FUNCTION2;
```

Comment: Note that `CODE1` and `CODE2` have to be able to evaluate to some value, otherwise this won't work. For example, you can `print` but not `echo`, because `print` returns 1 while `echo` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @BoltClock: You actually can use void functions (`(true) ? flush() : flush();` works just fine), but this is one of these odd cases where `echo` does not behave like a function... I've fixed my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : "0";` is a ternary if statement. The conditional is the part preceding the `?`. The first part after the `?` is the value to assign if the expression is true. The part after the `:` is the assignment resulting from a false value for the expression.

Answer (score 0):

It is called [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).
Your second question - `$_POST['page']` and `$page` are not the same, if you want to check the variable, you need to test $_POST variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is passing the NaN as a string to your PHP script. You could try this:

```
$page = isset($_POST['page']) && $_POST['page'] != "NaN" ? $_POST['page'] : "0";
```

Or you could alter your javascript to do the check that side:

```
count += num;
if (isNaN(count))
{
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: No don't try that. That's putting a bandage on a bug without fixing the bug. Fix the bug that creates the NaN in the first place. Adding "patches" like that to fix issues in your code will eventually lead to an unmaintainable mess.